# equality holds for $n = t−1$ if $t$ is the least common denominator of the $r_k$, proof explanation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, proof-verification

Let $r_1, r_2, . . . , r_m$ be a given set of positive rational numbers whose sum is $1$. Define the function $f$ by $f(n) = n − \sum_{k=1}^{m}⌊r_kn⌋$ for each positive integer $n$. Find the minimum and maximum values of $f(n)$.

Solution: Of course $⌊r_kn⌋ ≤ r_kn$, so $f(n) ≥ 0$, with equality for $n = 0$, so $0$ is the minimum value.
 On the other hand, we have $r_kn−⌊r_kn⌋ < 1$, so $f(n) ≤ m−1$. Here equality holds for $n = t−1$ if $t$ is the least common denominator of the $r_k$.

I need help understanding the proof of how the equality holds for $n = t−1$ if $t$ is the least common denominator of the $r_k$, how does this determine that m-1 is the maximum.

Answer (score -1):

If $t$ is the least common denominator of the $r_k$, then

$$\lfloor r_k(t-1)\rfloor=\lfloor r_k t-r_k\rfloor=r_k t -1$$

The second equality follows from the fact that $r_kt$ is an integer since $t$ is a common denominator of all the $r_k$ together with the fact that $0<r_k<1$, so from an integer we are subtracting a number smaller than $1$ and then we round down, which leaves us with the integer minus $1$.

Now we evaluate

\begin{align*}
t-1-\sum_{k=1}^m\lfloor r_k\rfloor &= t-1-\left(\sum_{k=1}^mr_kt-\sum_{k=1}^m1\right)\\
&= t-1-t+m\\
&=m-1
\end{align*}